# Clarify the use of bind in this context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Can someone help explain what is the use of bind in this context is?

```
<button onClick={this.add.bind(null, 'Bacon tuna')} className="button-info-create">Add New</button>
```

https://youtu.be/OKRu7i49X54?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBuKtLgPR_zWYnrwv-JllpA&t=3m3s

From what I understand, when null passed to bind, **this** refers to the global scope. Yet somehow it is seems to be referring to the **Board** instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.createClass()` will automatically bind `this` values correctly for us, but changes when using ES6 classes affect `this`, [source](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/#this-differences)

This is the reason why on the video, `bind(null, 'something')` could be used even if `add()` method is using `this.setState()`. If you try to use `bind(null, ...)` with `extends React.Component` instead of `React.createClass`, it will not work.

If you open [the source link](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/#this-differences), you can read very detailed and longer explanation by Todd Motto.

Answer (score 3):

bind allows you to seed arguments into the resulting function.

> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])

so that is calling this.add, passing in null for the context (which is ignored when the constructor is called with new), and seeding "bacon tuna" for the first argument.

you can read more about function.prototype.bind here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind